If $f$ is increasing real valued function and $g$ is defined as following then $g$ is increasing and right continuous.
Let $f:[a,b]\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ be increasing function. Now define, $g:[a,b]\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x)= f(x+)$ for all $x\in [a,b)$ and $g(b)=f(b)$. Now prove that $g$ is increasing function and $g$ is right continuous.
$f(x+)= inf\{f(t) | x<t\leq b\}$ for all $x\in[a,b)$. Since $f$ is increasing function so $f(x+)$ exists for all $x\in[a,b)$.
Now since for $x<y$ so $\{f(t) | y<t\leq b\}\subset\{f(t)| x<t\leq b\}$. Therefore $g(x)\leq g(y)$.
But I am not sure about the right continuous.
What I need, for $y\in [a,b)$ I need to show that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $y< x< y +\delta$ implies that $| g(x) - g(y) | < \epsilon$ and since $g$ is increasing function so $g(y)\leq g(x)$.

For any $x_0\in[a,b)$, we have
$$g(x_0)=\lim_{t\to x_0^+}f(t),$$
then for any given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that, when $t\in(x_0,x_0+\delta)\subset[a,b)$, we have
$|f(t)-g(x_0)|<\epsilon/2$.
So when $x\in(x_0,x_0+\delta/2)$, we get
\begin{align*}
  |g(x)-g(x_0)|
  &=\left|\lim_{t\to x^+}f(t)-g(x_0)\right|\\
  &=\left|\lim_{t\to x^+}[f(t)-g(x_0)]\right|\\
  &=\lim_{t\to x^+}|f(t)-g(x_0)|\\
  &\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
  &<\epsilon.
\end{align*}
Hence, we have
$$\lim_{x\to x_0^+}g(x)=g(x_0).$$

And what about $x_0 = b$ ?

@Texas  your $g(b)$ is defined by $g(b)=f(b)$, we cann only consider left limit at $b$,   but it  maybe not left continuous. For example $f(x)=x,x\in[0,1),f(1)=2$, and then $g(x)=x,x\in[0,1),g(1)=2$.

so we don't need right continuous at b.

W e even cann't define the right limit at $b$!

Got it, thank you
